# Windows Update - BSOD

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, bsod, windows-update, dell-latitude

Good Morning,

A windows update seems to have hosed two of my laptops, same make/model.  Dell Latitude E7470.  I just installed windows and was doing updates, I rebooted for what I believe was the last batch up updates and now both are blue screening with 0x6F.

### **Full Error:**

Session3_Initialization_Failed

Technical Information

### Stop: 0X6F (0XFFFFFFFFC000012F)

**Things I've tried:**

- Startup repair
- System Restore
- Copying the regback files back to the config folder
- check disk
- `SFC /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=c:\windows`
- MacriumReflects BootFix
- EasyRe Automated Repair
- LastKnownGood Config
- Safemode

Nothing seems to make them boot back up.  Any ideas?

Comment: Bug Check 0x6F = SESSION3_INITIALIZATION_FAILED: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559156.aspx can you share the dmp files are post the value from te 1st parameter?

Comment: Thats the other thing I forgot to mention that is strange.  It's not creating a dmp file.  It's as though a dump never happened, the minidump folder was never even created after the dump.  Give me a sec and i'll post the parameter

Comment: Session3_Initialization_Failed
Technical Information
***Stop: 0X6F (0XFFFFFFFFC000012F)

Comment: STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_NOT_MZ so a DLL/Exe/SYS is not a valid windows file. if sfc can't fix it, restore a backup

Comment: Hoping this is not off-topic - could anyone explain to me why this question would be downvoted? Seems reasonably elaborate to me.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I sure thought I was elaborate and was genuinely looking for help for an issue that others may also experience.  Not sure why it got downvoted.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion MagicAndre, This is a fresh build though on both devices, I hadn't made a backup yet as I was still finishing loading all the windows updates. At this point, I guess it wouldn't be hard to reinstall, but I'd rather find out why it happened and what update might have caused it so this doesn't happen to other laptops in our organization.

Comment: I have no idea why you see this on a fresh install. try again and when Windows is up and running make a backup.

Comment: Thanks for those of you that replied.  After much research I think this is related to Dell DDP Encryption.  I'm working on decrypting the drive now.

Comment: were you able to verify that the issue is caused by Dell DDP Encryption? Are the issues gone when you don't use it? Have you considered using Bitlocker?

Comment: Got it back up and running. once it was decrypted I was able to go into the winsxs folder and rename the pending.xml file to pending.old and then because a reboot was no longer pending for the update that was failing it allowed me to run sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=c:\windows and then when I rebooted it came back up.

Comment: ok, post your finding as answer, I'll upvote it and you can accept your own reply later as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it back up and running. once it was decrypted from Dells DDP Encryption, I was able to go into the winsxs folder and rename the `pending.xml` file to pending.old and then because a reboot was no longer pending for the update that was failing it allowed me to run `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=c:\windows` which found corrupt system files and then when I rebooted it came back up.

Comment: ok, I added Dell DDP Encryption, so that other can find it easier. not everyone reads all comments.